# How to add infinite scrolling to a list of cards? [ReactJS]

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been working on a pokedex project that allows me to display a list of pokecards.

the code for the PokemonList.js is as follows

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PokemonCard from "./PokemonCard";
import axios from "axios";

export default class PokemonList extends Component {
  state = {
    url: "http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=200",
    pokemon: null,
    itemsCountPerPage: 20,
    activePage: 1
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const res = await axios.get(this.state.url);
    this.setState({ pokemon: res.data["results"] });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.pokemon);
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {this.state.pokemon ? (
          <div className="row">
            {this.state.pokemon.map(pokemon => (
              <PokemonCard
                key={pokemon.name}
                name={pokemon.name}
                url={pokemon.url}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        ) : (
          <h1>Loading Pokemon</h1>
        )}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

I have been trying to use infinite scroller addons such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroller but I've never seemed to get it to work. How could I apply infinite scrolling that'd load 20 cards at a time?

-----------------EDIT--------------------------------
[image]

Comment: Why was that package not working? How are you retrieving additional items after the user reached the end of the list? From the look of this component https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroller, your logic to load additional items should be in `loadMore` function.

Comment: @leopic  so I'd just put in my PokemonCard item in loadmore? And where would I put the infinity scroller code?

Comment: You see how in your `componentDidMount` function you make a `GET` request to load the initial 20 Pokémon? You need to make subsequent calls to keep... catching them all :). If you look at the response from your request there is a `next` property in there, that's the URL you need to hit

Comment: IMO, [don't use infinite scroll](https://hackernoon.com/stop-infinite-scrolling-on-your-website-now-ie6rg31eu). Also I don't think your component should contain implementation details like API URLs or calls. Pass-in those capabilities as props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to implement an infinite scroll using this API:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import InfiniteScroll from "react-infinite-scroller";

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=200",
    pokemon: [],
    itemsCountPerPage: 20,
    activePage: 1
  };

  loadPokemon = () => {
    axios
      .get(this.state.url)
      .then(res => {
        this.setState(prevState => {
          return {
            pokemon: [...prevState.pokemon, ...res.data.results],
            url: res.data.next
          };
        });
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  render() {
    // console.log(this.state.pokemon);
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {this.state.pokemon ? (
          <div className="row">
            <InfiniteScroll
              pageStart={0}
              loadMore={this.loadPokemon}
              hasMore={this.state.url}
              loader={
                <div className="loader" key={0}>
                  Loading ...
                </div>
              }
            >
              {this.state.pokemon.map((pokemon, i) => (
                <div
                  style={{ borderBottom: "1px solid", padding: "10px" }}
                  key={pokemon.name + i}
                >
                  <div>{pokemon.name}</div>
                  <div>{pokemon.url}</div>
                </div>
              ))}
            </InfiniteScroll>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <h1>Loading Pokemon</h1>
        )}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

You can see it up and running in a codesandbox here:

[image: Edit bitter-paper-9sleu]

Comment: How could I load my pre-made PokemonCard's(.js) I edited the question to show what it looks like now.

Comment: I actually managed to get it to work, but for some reason, if I set the API to load 10 pokemon cards, it would repeat the first 10 and then start loading the rest in an appropriate order. so the first 10 or 20 or whatever number is set would be duplicated before the list carries on. What would cause that?

Comment: Are you calling the `loadPokemon` function inside `componentDidMount()`?

Comment: You can create a codesandbox so it will be easier to help you out!